# Access vue components passed via a slot Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-slot

**Problem desription**

I am trying to access Vue child components passed in a slot.

I do it with the following approach:
`this.$slots.default()`

I receive the components and I can even access and call methods of a component using the following approach:
`this.$slots.default()[1].type.methods.methodName`

The problem is that within the child component `this` keyword  has now changed to another type where you can only access methods defined in that component and restricted variables. And so for example you can't access this.$refs (which I actually need) or this.$el or anything else except defined methods and some variables.

**What I've tried**

I've tried assigning this.$refs to a variable within the onmount function and then trying to access it when calling a method from the parent component, but you can't access that variable.

In Vue2 you have full access to the child component and this would work.

Is there a way to fix it in Vue3?

Comment: Please, show the whole example and explain what you want to achieve. It looks like XY problem. "access and call methods of a component using the following approach" - this looks like bad design and should be never done under normal circumstances.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in Vue3 since VNodes are context-free. See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/2.